# react native what does nestedScrollEnabled do?

Tags: react-native

This property available on the ScrollViewProps or components that derive props from it (SectionList, FlatList, VirtualizedList) is bugging me ever since I met the docs the first time.

The description only says `Enables nested scrolling for Android API level 21+.` but does not give more insight on what is actually wrong on API 21+ (or on API < 21 for that matter) or the actual use cases where you would need this property.

I have done multiple tests on real android devices, and on all of them, nested scrolls (either with ScrollView or the other stock components) worked properly - with or without this prop set to true - and in both horizontal and vertical directions.

So then, what does this prop actually do? Can you provide an example where this prop does anything useful or where the scroll does not work properly without it?

Also, does it harm if I just set it to true no matter what for all of these scrolling components ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By accord with [Android's website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView)

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

Wich means:

> NestedScrollView is when you need a scrollView inside another scrollView

This is enable by default on newer versions of android, and all IOS versions, but you can set this to `true` and it will works on everything.

Example use:

[image]

Comment: It was clear to me from the beginning what it was supposed to do - allowing to scroll child scrolls in nested scrolls. However, I still cannot find a reason for this prop to exist - even less if the Android docs state that it is enabled by default and the react native docs imply by the prop name that is disabled by default and has no effect when turned on/off...

Comment: Yes, this doesn't affect nothing after all. So, question solved?

Comment: @cristian question solved? Mark as solved if it helped you, thanks!